# Can CppUnit be used for embedded systems?

Tags: c++, embedded, cppunit

I know it's possible to use CppUnit Lite for embedded systems, but is it also the case with CppUnit?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know a website explaining how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer in INSTALL file...

> If you want to *use* a cross compiler, that generates code for a
>   platform different from the build platform, you should specify the
>   host platform (i.e., that on which the generated programs will
>   eventually be run) with `--host=TYPE`. In this case, you should also
>   specify the build platform with `--build=TYPE`, because, in this case,
>   it may not be possible to guess the build platform (it sometimes
>   involves compiling and running simple test programs, and this can't be
>   done if the compiler is a cross compiler).